# SQL - Get highest and lowest record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with events, each having a start- and end date. Now I want to get (using only 1 SQL in PHP) the event with the latest end date and the event with the earliest start date. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the two rows, rather than just the dates, probably want to use `UNION`

```
SELECT * from table 
  ORDER BY end_date DESC 
  LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * from table 
  ORDER BY start_date ASC 
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ehh may need parens there with the LIMITs now that I think about it. Let me go try it in a fiddle

Comment: Shouldn't need parenthesis (a UNION is "outside" a SELECT). Although I suggest using `UNION ALL` except in cases where duplicate folding *is* a desired aspect.

Comment: First one should be `end_date`, not `start_date`.

Comment: Good call, updated. Next time I'll read the whole question :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate), Max(EndDate) 
From yourTable
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what the OP wants

Comment: This just returns the dates, not the associated records.

Comment: I am not sure WHAT the heck the OP wants. He didn't say whether he wanted the record or not. Technically he asked "Does anyone know how  do this?" so the correct answer to his question is "Yes"

Comment: Anyone who speaks English fluently knows that that's an idiomatic way to ask for a way, not intended to be answered literally. He said he wanted "the events". So even if that doesn't mean the whole record, it's still clearly not just the dates.

Comment: Thanks for the English lesson and the free side of attitude.